# onReceive not called for broadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am sending a broadcast from broadcast receiver. But unlike creating a `new intent()` I want to use existing intent. so my code goes like this

```
    Intent myIntent = getIntent();      
    myIntent.setAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    sendBroadcast(myIntent);
```

Note that line 1 uses `getIntent()` instead of `new Intent()`. If am using new Intent() everything goes fine, except off course I miss the thing which was there in getIntent()'s intent.

Any idea how to do that. If u need any piece of code feel free to ask. Thanks!!!

**Update**

Code for receiving the broadcast message. AS mentioned earlier, if I am using new Intent() everything works fine, so I don't think any problem with receiver.

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {   
            if (intent.getAction() == NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED && isTopActivity())
            {
                getController().onTagTouch(intent);
            }
        }
    };
```

This all lead me for one more question. **Is there some limitation with the size of intent we send as broadcast?**

Comment: Why do you want to use the existing Intent? Share the declaration of your Receiver from either Manifest or the Java code.